# how to set button enable and disbale in ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am creating 2 buttons one for like and one for dislike when i  click like button its disable and also disable dislike button same time.and so on. and its not change when i am run the application second time. i am implemented for that its work but problem is that when i run my application second time once again that button enable. problem is that i don't want that button same button enable.please help me what is the problem in my code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0 
        green:102/255.0 blue:204/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = 
        @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};

        smsdisplaytext.editable=NO;

        smsdisplaytext.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.0 green:102/255.0 
        blue:204/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        self.navigationItem.title=@"Insta SMS";

         [ self getSmsData];
         [self smsdisplay];
         [self getLike];
         }




            -(void)sendlike
          {

           NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
           @"http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/AddRatingForSMS"];

           ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

           [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1] forKey:@"t"];

            [request setPostValue:@"admin" forKey:@"h"];
             [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.Id] forKey:@"cid"];
           [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1234567890] forKey:@"token"];
            [request setPostValue:@"test@test.com" forKey:@"email"];
            [request setTag:2];


            [request setPostValue:@"true" forKey:@"like"];


            [request setDelegate:self];
            [request startAsynchronous];

               }
           -(void)senddislike
          {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
        @"http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/AddRatingForSMS"];

       ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

      [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1] forKey:@"t"];

      [request s  etPostValue:@"admin" forKey:@"h"];
      [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.Id] forKey:@"cid"];
      [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1234567890] forKey:@"token"];
      [request setPostValue:@"test@test.com" forKey:@"email"];
      [request setPostValue:@"false" forKey:@"Like"];
      [request setTag:3];

      [request setDelegate:self];
      [request startAsynchronous];

      }
      - (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    {
      NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
     responseString = [request responseString];
     NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
    if(request.tag==1)
     {
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] ;

    NSArray *jsondata = [parser objectWithString:responseString];

        NSLog(@"%@",jsondata);
    for (NSObject* item in jsondata)
    {
        likelabel.text = [[item valueForKey:@"Liked"] stringValue];
        dislikelabel.text = [[item valueForKey:@"Disliked"] stringValue];
    }


      }
   else if(request.tag==2)
    {
    [self getLike];

     }
   ///////  getting comment

   else if(request.tag==4)
    {
        // get comments

        SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] ;

        NSMutableArray *jsondata = [parser objectWithString:responseString];


        for(int i=0;i<jsondata.count;i++)
        {
            NSObject *temp = [jsondata objectAtIndex:i];


            NSMutableDictionary *message = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



            message[kMessageContent]=[temp valueForKey:@"Comment"];
            message[@"Timestamp"]=[self dateWithJSONString:[temp valueForKey:@"CreatedDate"]];

            last=[[temp valueForKey:@"Id"] integerValue];

            [_chatController addNewMessage:message];


            }
      }
     else
     {
        ////post comment
        [self getComment];
    }

    }
```

//this method for getting like and dislike

```
  -(void)getLike
   {

   NSString *url = [NSString 
   stringWithFormat:@"http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/GetRatingsForSMS?
   t=1&h=admin&cid=%@&token=1234567890&email=test@test.com",self.Id];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
   [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setTag:1];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];

     }
```

// here for like button

```
    - (IBAction)btnlike:(id)sender
    {
         NSLog(@"keypress");

         [self sendlike];
         [self getLike];

         UIButton *btnlike = (UIButton *) sender;

           btnlike.enabled = NO;
          UIButton *btndislike = (UIButton *) sender;

            btndislike.enabled = NO;

        }
```

//here i am action for dislike button

```
       - (IBAction)btndislike:(id)sender
        {
            NSLog(@"keypress");
           [self senddislike];
           [self getLike];
            UIButton *btndislike = (UIButton *) sender;
           btndislike.enabled = NO;
             _btnlike.enabled = NO;

        }



        @end
```

Comment: In your `btnlike:` method, you are setting `enabled = NO` twice on the same button (`sender`)... I don't understand the rest of your question and this code is pretty hard to follow. Can you clarify it in any way?

Comment: In IBAction you are creating new button it is why? I did not understand your code but i guess it will be easier for you if you will create buttons only once and just enable & disable them. You may also use yourButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES or NO.

Comment: i have two button one like and one for dislike when i click like or dislike  button its going to disable both like and dislike .at same time.

Comment: it work for first time but i run my app second time its show me button enable at same message. idon't want enable for same task.

Comment: OK , try to create your buttons in h. file, This (IBAction)btndislike:(id)sender action is connected with btndislike button?

Comment: U using storyboard or xib? or your buttons created programatically?

Comment: using nib file with drag and drop button

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not an native english speaker, I hope I've understood correctly what you are trying to achieve.

If I understand correctly, You have a 'Like' and 'Dislike' buttons, and when the user presses on one of them, you want both to be disabled,
Which is working correctly for the current run.
But, if I understand correctly, the next time the app runs, the buttons are 'reset' to be enabled, and you don't want that,
You want the button be disabled every time the app runs.

If I did understood you correctly, the way to 'save' state of objects is using the `NSUserDefaults`.

You might have a better way to implement it than my example below, but it should do the trick, and also give you a better understanding on how to implement it, incase you need to modify my code.

Add the following method:

```
-(void)disableButtons {  
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: YES forKey: @"buttonsDisabled"];  
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];  
}
```

now, at the end of the 'Like' and 'Dislike' buttons, just call the following methods by adding to your code:

```
[self disableButtons]
```

Now, add the following to `viewDidLoad`:

```
// someplace in viewDidLoad  
BOOL bottunsDisabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"buttonsDisabled"];  
if(buttonsDisabled) {  
    self.btndislike.enabled = NO;  
    self.btnlike.enabled = NO;  
}
```

The buttons defaults state are enabled, so the above code will change them, incase they have been disabled in previous runs.
Note that I also assumed you have a reference to the buttons (I assume you've created them in interface builder), if not, just create a property/ivar that will hold a reference to them.

And as ***Ian MacDonald*** mentioned above, in the 'Like' button method, you are disabling only the 'Like' button twice, and not disabling the 'Dislike' button.
In order to fix it, change the code to the following (again, I assume you have some sort of reference to both of them):

```
- (IBAction)btnlike:(id)sender  
{  
     NSLog(@"keypress");  

     [self sendlike];  
     [self getLike];  

     self.btnlike.enabled = NO;  
     self.btndislike.enabled = NO;  

     [self disableButtons];  
    }
```

As I've said above, I'm not an native english speaker,
So I hope my answer was clear enough.
If something isn't clear, just tell me and I'll try to rephrase it.

Good luck mate!